# Write query to export database to csv file via Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sqlcmd

I am trying to write a query that will export the data from a table into a csv file.  I cannot use the manual methods of right clicking the results and selecting save as.  It has to be via query.  I turned on the SQLCMD mode on my Managment Studio and am trying to run this cmd:

```
sqlcmd -S sqlbusServer -d hhhdb -E -Q "SELECT * FROM Table" 
   -o "MyData.csv" -h-1 -s"," -w 700
```

in the above code sqlbusServer is the name of the server, and hhhdb is the database name.

I keep getting an error "Incorrect syntax near 'S'.  Am I correct in just putting in the server name and db name without any ',", or [ around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
:!!sqlcmd -S sqlbusServer -d hhhdb -E -Q "SELECT * FROM Table" 
-o "FILEPATH\MyData.csv" -h-1 -s"," -w 700
```

I simply added **:!!** front of "sqlcmd" and a **filepath** in front of the document name.

Examples:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1017732/SQL-Server-export-to-CSV

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused. The sqlcmd is a command line tool. You would execute that from a DOS prompt, not from SSMS.

It's been awhile since I used it, but your syntax looks correct though.

Comment: Yeah, I but I thought that if you turned SQLCMD mode on through Management Studios you could use it in there as well.